# Postgres template0 template1 both removed

Tags: postgresql, osx-elcapitan

I mistakenly dropped both postgres's template0 and template1 and now am unable to create databases. I am currently running postgres 9.5.3 on OSX 10.11. Can I get help restoring these two templates; I have already tried an uninstall/re-install using homebrew with no luck.

Comment: `select datname,datistemplate from pg_database;` what this query returns?..

Comment: datname lists <user> datistemplate lists f (only one row is displayed as expected)

Comment: make a dump of your user database and just run `initdb`

Answer (score 1):

you cannot to drop database template0 - not with any legal method. What you can do? Now, your database cluster is broken, there are two possibilities:

1. backup your current databases with `pg_dump`. Create new database cluster with [`initdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html). New database cluster will have correct template0, template1
2. You can try to create template1 from any existing database - you can use clause `TEMPLATE` of statement `CREATE DATABASE`:

```
postgres=# create database template1 template postgres;
ERROR:  database "template1" already exists
postgres=# create database template0 template postgres;
ERROR:  database "template0" already exists
```

First method should be preferred, because nobody knows, what is broken in your cluster.

Comment: yo ucan update `datistemplate` field to `true` and then just drop it

Answer (score 0):

you must create the new database with sqlmanager for postgresql, template0 appears there

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).